# Access updated lambda version from command: `aws lambda publish-version`

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, aws-lambda, aws-cli

My CI pipeline will do two things

- generate new lambda version and publish
- Update an alias to point at that new version

This will be done via cli commands. My question is, how do I access the version number that been generated from the first command. It is returned and posted to the CLI. Can this be access easily via some nifty was command or will I have to parse it myself?

e.g.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works but still curious if there is a better way.

`version=$(aws lambda publish-version --function-name test_lambda --description "updated via cli" --region eu-west-1| jq '.Version')`

Comment: version=$(aws lambda publish-version --function-name test_lambda --description "updated via cli" --region eu-west-1 | jq '.Version | tonumber')

Needs to be an int to use in the update-alias command

Answer (score 2):

```
version=$(aws lambda publish-version \
  --function-name test_lambda --description "updated via cli" --region eu-west-1 \
  --query Version \
  --output text)
```

See [Controlling Command Output from the AWS Command Line Interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/controlling-output.html) page of AWS CLI User Guide, specifically [How to Filter the Output with the --query Option](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/controlling-output.html#controlling-output-filter) and [Text Output Format](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/controlling-output.html#text-output)

Comment: Might need to add the double quotes to the `--query` param

Answer (score 0):

```
NEW_LAMBDA_VERSION=$(aws lambda list-versions-by-function --function-name $LAMBDA_NAME_FOR_DEPLOY --no-paginate --query "max_by(Versions, &to_number(to_number(Version) || '0'))")
NEW_LAMBDA_VERSION=$(echo $NEW_LAMBDA_VERSION | jq -r .Version)
echo $NEW_LAMBDA_VERSION
```

In this case, I use on .gitlab-ci.yml.

[image]